# Downloading and burning a live CD

Tags: boot

Can I download and burn a live cd on my laptop then use that cd to install an os on my mothers desktop? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just be sure that the OS you want to use fits on the medium you're trying to install it on. For example, the latest versions of Ubuntu do not fit on a CD, and require either a DVD or USB drive. Also be sure the computer you wish to install on meets the necessary system requirements for the operating system.